# Help understanding staccato notation

Tags: staccato

[image]

Hello, in this passage of Bach's Italian concerto Presto, Are just the first notes of the base line played staccato? or is this shorthand for all the base notes to be played staccato?

Answer (score 13):

Just the first note of each bar of the notated bassline is staccato. **The slurs over the rest of the notes in the bassline mark that they should be played legato instead.**